# Can't convert currentTime to String

Tags: java, tostring

This is my code:

```
 public void idoKiiras(){
    String idostring = new String();
    idostring.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.print(idostring);
    ido.setText(idostring);
}
```

What i get in the string is nothing, it's empty. Any solution?

Comment: Use `System.nanoTime()` for better accuracy. [link] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`String.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28long%29) is a `static` method that returns a `String` value. Use it like so

```
String idostring = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.print(idostring);
ido.setText(idostring);
```

Previously, you were using the `valueOf` method but not doing anything with its return value.

```
idostring.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Remember that `String` objects are immutable. No `String` method will ever change the `String` internally, it will always return a new `String` object.

Comment: Thanks, it's work. It's a little late, i write some stupid things. (and I found a second solution, I don't know which one is better, String idostring = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()); )

Comment: @minnera You are welcome. If you look at the source code of `String.valueOf(long)`, it calls `Long.toString(yourValue);`, so they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

@Sotirios already answered this, beautifully, but, I just want to give you a little tip to help anyone that has this problem.

Set the idostring to a silly value at the initialisation phase that way you can see whether it is being changed from the various methods.

E.g

`String idostring = "THIS_SHOULD_CHANGE";`

That way, when you get to setting the text of ido, you won't have a blank label/button/textview.